# localSettings.Containers[containername] - The given key was not present

Tags: c#, crash

I am looping through code looking for localsettings.  When a container is null it gives the error message "The given key was not present in the dictionary".  How can I check to see it the container is null so it doesn't crash the code?

```
if ((Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer)localSettings.Containers[containername] != null)
```

This gives the same error

```
var container = localSettings.Containers[containername];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        //This checks if the given container name exists or not
        if(settings.Containers.ContainsKey("containerName"))
        { 
            if(settings.Containers["ContainerName"].Values.ContainsKey("your data key"))
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps